# Development for Windows CE 5.0 using VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sdk, windows-ce

I have installed a SDK for a custom Windows CE device buiilt with Windows-CE Platform Builder 5.0.

I used to use VS2005 on Windows XP (32 bit) with this SDK and it works perfect. Now I switch VS2008 on Windows 7 (64 bit).

The installation has been successfull. Now I want to develop for that device. When I try to create a new SmartDeviceProject I get all existing Windows-CE platforms offered except the custom SDK. What must I do to use VS2008 for development for a Windows CE 5.0 custom device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is essential to install the SDK with `runas /user:Administrator "msiexec /i MYSDK.msi"`.

Although the installation looks like successful it just failed somehow. The MSI that has been crerated by Platform Builder looks like being not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the SDK *after* Studio 2008 (i.e. you didn't just install Studio 2008 on the machine that already had 2005 and the SDK)?  The device development tools are very, very particular about install order, and side-by-side installs are tenuous at best.

Comment: Chris, The VS2005 is on the XP machine, the VS2008 on the Win7 one. I installed the SDK today while the VS2008 had been installed years(?) ago. There is no VS2005 on Win7(64).

Comment: @harper Did you see any errors during installation? The only issue I have had with WINCE SDK installations was caused by invalid configuration files that were abandoned by VS2005 even after removing it from my system. Could this be your scenario? Did you ever have VS2005 on your Win7 system.

Comment: I had tried to installed VS2005. The installation never completed. IIRC the installer told that VS2005 will not run. Probably I tried to install it anyway. Finnaly I gave up VS2005 und choosed VS2008, but now I need to connect to the WinCE device. Did you managed to clean you Win7 from VS2005 residuals? I did not see any error during the SDK installation.